# Delete a set of positions from a Python list

Tags: python, list

Although this should be rather easily done with a for loop, I'm wondering wether there is a concise way to delete a set of positions from a Python list. E.g.:

```
l = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
pos = [4,6]
# Is there something close to
l.remove(pos)
```

Best

Comment: Yes. It is a duplicate. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[del](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) is what you are looking for if you *have consecutive indices*:

From the documentation:

> There is a way to remove an item from a list given its index instead of its value: the del statement

Otherwise, you could generate a new list, by filtering out indices, which you aren't interested in

```
result = [x for i, x in enumerate(l) if i not in pos]
```

Comment: How does `del` delete a *set* of positions?

Comment: @StefanPochmann depends, if you have a _set_ of consecutive indices, it'll work.

Comment: So the indexes in their example `[4,6]` are consecutive?